# How can I convert a NameValueCollection to a KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, keyvaluepair, namevaluecollection

I want to convert a [NameValueCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) to a [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.2). Is there a way to do this easily for just a single value in a NameValueCollection?

I have this right now but it seems kind of verbose:

```
private KeyValuePair<string, string> GetEtagHeader(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    var etagValue = collection.Get(HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch.ToString());

    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch.ToString(), etagValue);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that name value collection - like http headers allows single key with multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much shorter you can get it.

One possibility is to put the Get in where you create the KeyValuePair

```
private static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetEtagHeader(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    string key = HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch.ToString();
    return new KeyValuePair(key, collection.Get(key));
}
```

That should serve your case.  I'd go a step further and split it into 2 methods - one for your specific case and one generic helper.

```
private static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetEtagHeader(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    return ToKeyValuePair(HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch.ToString(), collection);
}

private static KeyValuePair<string, string> ToKeyValuePair(string key, NameValueCollection collection)
{
    return new KeyValuePair(key, collection.Get(key));
}
```

Comment: These methods should be `static` since they don't reference any members of the enclosing class. Better yet, they could be extension methods with a `this NameValueCollection collection` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It would be less verbose if you put `HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch.ToString()` into a temp variable and instead inline the temp `etagValue`:

```
private KeyValuePair<string, string> GetEtagHeader(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    string key = HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch.ToString();
    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, collection.Get(key));
}
```

Comment: The method should be `static` since it doesn't reference any members of the enclosing class. Better yet, it could be an extension method with a `this NameValueCollection collection` parameter.

Comment: Yes, unless `HttpRequestHeader` is an instance property.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd define an extension method like this one:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public KeyValuePair<string,string> GetPair(this NameValueCollection source, string key)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>
        (
            key,
            source.Get(key)
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can just write your original code like this:

```
private KeyValuePair<string, string> GetEtagHeader(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    return collection.GetPair(HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch.ToString());
}
```